# Convert worldfile for jpg to worldfile for png

Tags: python, gdal, world-file

I am using 3 band jpeg files with 1 band png masks for image analysis. The names match except for extension, and I am merging the jpgs using gdalbuildvrt, then gdal_translate to generate a geotiff. I would like to merge the pngs in the same manner (reusing my existing scripts if possible), but my mask generator does not create a worldfile.

Example files:

```
tileset_nn_0_0.jpg
tileset_nn_0_0.jpg.aux.xml
tileset_nn_0_0.png
tileset_nn_1_0.jpg
tileset_nn_1_0.jpg.aux.xml
tileset_nn_1_0.png
tileset_nn_2_0.jpg
...
```

The worldfile I have for the jpgs is a PAM/GDAL dataset, and looking inside the files, they won't work by just renaming because they include attributes regarding JPEG compression, bands, etc that don't exist in the pngs.

I have thought of using gdal_translate to convert each jpg image to a grayscale png in a temp directory, then delete the png and copy the worldfile out, but I will be doing this repeatedly for several datasets, so I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: What are your scripts written in? To georeference a PNG you only need the SRS and GeoTransform elements from the XML - everything else is optional. Some python code to read one XML and write another with only those tags can be done in a few lines. There might even be a command-line processor to do it...

Comment: related (pgw) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84363/how-to-georeference-my-png-using-gdal

Comment: Does anyone have an example xml file for a png?

Comment: Edit your JPG metafile and leave only the SRS and GeoTransform - rename it and save it and that will be a valid metadatafile for a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments by Spacedman, I put together the following script which works in my case:

```
import glob
import os
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree

srcpath = 'D:/jpglocation/'
destpath = 'D:/pnglocation/'
filemask = '*.jpg.aux.xml'

wfs = glob.glob(f'{srcpath}{filemask}')
i = 0
for wf in wfs:
    et = ElementTree.parse(wf)
    root = et.getroot()

    # Strip jpg metadata
    for metadata in root.findall('Metadata'):
        root.remove(metadata)
    for metadata in root.findall('PAMRasterBand'):
        root.remove(metadata)

    #add png metadata
    #domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE"
    metaImg = ElementTree.SubElement(root, "Metadata", domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE")
    #<MDI key="INTERLEAVE">PIXEL</MDI>
    mdi = ElementTree.Element("MDI", key="INTERLEAVE")
    mdi.text = "PIXEL"
    metaImg.append(mdi)

    meta = ElementTree.SubElement(root, "Metadata")
    mdi = ElementTree.Element("MDI", key="AREA_OR_POINT")
    mdi.text = "AREA"
    meta.append(mdi)
    mdi = ElementTree.Element("MDI", key="COLORSPACE")
    mdi.text = "RGB"
    meta.append(mdi)
    mdi = ElementTree.Element("MDI", key="COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET")
    mdi.text = "1"
    meta.append(mdi)

    # Write back to file
    p = Path(wf)
    destfile = destpath + (p.stem).replace('.jpg', '.png') + '.xml'
    print(destfile)
    et.write(destfile)
```

And it works with gdalbuildvrt now to easily merge the png tiles into a larger composite:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list merged.vrt *.png
gdal_translate merged.vrt merged.tif
```

The worldfile didn't function with only SRS and GeoTransform, but it worked with generic png settings (my pngs are grayscale but the png metadata was from an RGB file).