# Georeferencing PNG image by GDAL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, gdal

I am not familiar with GDAL so far. Thereby I don't know how to start. By knowing the problem from the question below:

[Georeferencing PNG image in QGIS when the coordinates of image corners are known](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415272/georeferencing-png-image-in-qgis-when-the-coordinates-of-image-corners-are-known)

I would like to georeference the image by using the GDAL library. I don't want to [play with .pgw files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84363/georeferencing-png-using-gdal), because they are don't accurate enough I am afraid. Therefore I decided to use the GDAL option only for this purpose.
I found similar problem here:

[Georeferencing using GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27297/georeferencing-using-gdal)

but it didn't work for me

I found something better, which calls the GDAL library by Python code in pyQGIS

[How to call gdal_translate from Python code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/how-to-call-gdal-translate-from-python-code/42621)

and after applying the following code:

```
 from osgeo import gdal

 ds = gdal.Open('C:\my\Desktop current\Hey\cloakpN50E021.png')
 ds = gdal.Translate('C:\my\Desktop current\Hey\cloakpN50E021.tiff', ds, projWin = [-75.3, 
 5.5, -73.5, 3.7])
 ds = None
```

I have only the following command:

**>>>exec(open('C:/Users/k/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxoz9p370.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())**

which means, that the code is executed properly, but unfortunately I can see neither file transformed to .tiff nor the layer produced in QGIS.

What is missing here? Is it a chance to georeference the .png image this way?

I tried also the other method, by using the code below:

```
 gdal_translate --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 - 
 co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co 
 PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:31255 -a_ullr 9623.23 326346.38 
 9933.23 326090.63 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN50E021.png 
 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN50E021.tif
```

but i got the bunch of errors like this:

**ERROR 1: PredictorSetup:Horizontal differencing "Predictor" not supported with 2-bit samples**

Comment: Believe the error message and remove `-co PREDICTOR=2` from the command. See if some other errors remain. `--config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4` does not make sense with TIFF output, configuration option is for PDF.

Comment: Now I get: 'co' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Show your current command.

Comment: gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 - 
 co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:31255 -a_ullr 9623.23 326346.38 
 9933.23 326090.63 C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN50E021.png  C:\my\GDAL\cloakpN50E021.tif

Comment: You have a typo `- co NUM_THREADS` . Remove the space that truncates the command.

Comment: Ok I did and now: ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-a_ullr'

Comment: Copy-pasted your command `gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co TILED=YES -a_srs EPSG:31255 -a_ullr 9623.23 326346.38 9933.23 326090.63 test1.tif test2.tif` and it works for me.

Comment: Yesh! Now it works perfectly! Could you explain how to learn the GDAL commands?

Comment: Use the GDAL site https://gdal.org/, study old questions and answers in gis.stackexchange, read tutorials from the web, and experiment.